# Should I install redux if I already have installed flutter_redux

Tags: flutter, flutter-redux

I was setting up my app to use redux and had just installed [flutter_redux](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_redux) but noticed that class `Store` was not found to import which should be passed to `StoreProvider`. After installing `redux` package separately, imports were available. The [site](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_redux) says that `redux` is a dependency of this library so why should I install redux separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flutter_redux is a package for flutter side and can call builder after state change
and redux package is a dart side package for handle state and you should add fultter_redux and redux to your dependency

> A set of utilities that allow you to easily consume a Redux Store to
>   build Flutter Widgets.
>
> This package is built to work with **Redux.dart** 3.0.0+.

Comment: If ``redux`` is a dependency of ``flutter_redux`` then why should I install it again?

Comment: flutter_redux is a dependency of redux and i think package name can specified the difference

Comment: look redux package handle the store, reducers and states and flutter_redux pass the store to ui for render